# Why angular-ui/bootstrap directives placed in separated modules?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm developing some reusable components with AngularJS, I checked angular-ui/bootstrap to steal some ideas and best practices and I was surprised that they create one module per Bootstrap component.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap

Can anyone explain this? Should I follow this pattern in my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because some people might need just one component, and not necessarily all of them.

If your project is going to be an open-source set of components, you can consider that approach. Otherwise, there's probably no need for it.

The recommended way of structuring a "normal", larger application would be to group things that share a view into a module. So you might have an `admin` module, `messages` module... each with its components.

Comment: but anyway angular-ui-bootstrap.js and it's minified version contains all the modules in one files. So I actually load the whole code base on the page? I installed it using bower actually.

I this line in the beggining of the file:

angular.module("ui.bootstrap", ["ui.bootstrap.transition","ui.bootstrap.collapse","ui.bootstrap.accordion","ui.bootstrap.alert","ui.bootstrap.bindHtml......]);

Comment: I'm not sure about angular bootstrap now, but angular-ui components are available separately on bower. I would think that's the case with bootstrap as well (or at least should be)...

Comment: While angular-ui/bootstrap components are not available as individual bower components, you can create a custom build from the project's home page, containing only directives you need. This is the main reason to have separate modules for each directive. It also helps with unit testing as you can be sure to load only directive under test and eliminate any side effects.